# Are dimension of all eigenspaces even?

Tags: linear-algebra

question is: let $T∈L(V)$ be an operator one a real, finite dimensional vector space $V$. Assume $T$ has no non-zero eigenvectors. Let $P(x)$ be a non-constant, real monic polynomial. Prove that all the eigenspaces of $P(T)$ are even dimensional.

My thought is if $T$ has no non-zero eigenvectors, $V$ must be even dimensions, so $T$ could have no real eigenvalues and no non-zero eigenvectors. However, if $T$ has no eigenvalues, I think $P(T)$ also has no eigenvalues. If so, how could we prove this question?

Could someone give me any hint?

Comment: The claim seems to be false: take $T$ to be represented by $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $P(x)=x^2$.

Comment: @GregMartin Then $P(T)$ is represented by $\begin{pmatrix} -1  &0\\0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$ and the eigenspace associated with $-1$ (the only eigenspace) is even dimensional. Or are you talking about the poster's thought being false?

Comment: Aha, I see what you mean—my comment is wrong.

Comment: $P(T)$ may have real eigenvalues. See Greg Martin's comment.

Comment: "non-zero eigenvectors"??? Do you know the _definition_ of the word "eigenvector"?

Comment: normally eigenvectors are assumed non-zero so this is odd

Answer (score 0):

Say $W$ is an eigenspace of $P(T)$. It's easy to see that $T(W)\subset W$, so we ca define $S:W\to W$ by $S=T|_W$.

Now an eigenvector of $S$ would be an eigenvector of $T$, so $S$ has no eigenvectors. So $S$ has no real eigenvalues, which shows that $\dim(W)$ must be even, since a real polynomial of odd degree has a real root.

Comment: Why does a real polynomial of odd degree having a real root implies dim W is even?